# Компиляция Python в exe (миф или реальность)

Tags: python, компиляция, exe

Может кто-нибудь дать железобетонный ответ на эту тему (чтобы потом закрепить его и показывать как эталон)?

Является ли **компиляцией в exe** упаковка скрипта, библиотек и интерпретатора pyinstaller'ом (с учетом того, exe-шник который выступает лаунчером в pyinstaller'е скомпилирован заранее, а Python код просто вшивается в него, чтобы потом распаковаться в каталоге TEMP для реального запуска, подобно SFX)?

И существует ли на текущий момент хотя бы один настоящий (и рабочий!) компилятор Python кода в нативный exe-шник. (Трансляторы в С++ не в счет).

Comment: Нет, не является

Comment: `И существует ли на текущий момент хотя бы один настоящий (и рабочий!) компилятор Python кода в нативный exe-шник. (Трансляторы в С++ не в счет).` - "настоящего" компилятора нет. Но не понятно, чем не угодили трансляторы в C/C++.

Comment: "Но не понятно, чем не угодили трансляторы в C/C++." Вопрос был не об этом. 1)Угодили не угодили - это уже совсем не про это.2) Они все равно не в состоянии транслировать абсолютно все Python библиотеки в С++, чтобы потом получить через gcc\mingw автономный exe.

Answer (score 2):

Изначально Python это интерпретируемый язык
То есть как работает программа:
интерпретатор читает первую строку - выполняет
вторую ...
а компилятор сначала компилирует в набор машинных кодов а потом процессор их выполняет  (очень упрощённо)
нашёл картинку преимуществ и недостатков того и другого метода

[image: описание]

Фактически не транслируя(переводя) питон на компилируемые языки и не пользуясь библиотеками типо pyinstaller'a это сделать невозможно

Comment: Это неточный ответ. Python интерпретируемый язык с предварительной компиляцией в байткод. И это просто общие сведения. Мне же нужен аргументированный ответ профессионала, а не общие слова (я это все и так знаю; в вопросе написано - написать **железобетонный** ответ, который раз и навсегда закроет тему псевдокомпиляции Python всяким pyinstaller'ами ).