# Компиляция python программы в exe файл

Tags: python, компиляция, pygame, exe

Всем привет. У меня возникла такая проблема: пишу игру на python'е и хочу её скомпилировать в привычный всем *.exe файл. Структура папок и файлов следующая:

```
    core
        __init__.py
        gameobject.py
        spritesheet.py
    game
        buildlevel.py
        getlevel.py
        levelobjects.py
        renderer.py
    Media
        backgrounds
            sky01.png
        player
            player.png
        UI
            cursor.png
    main.py
    settings.py
```

Компилировать надо, соответственно, **main.py**. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1157961/398802

Comment: pyinstaller ????

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение! Проблема была в pymunk, т.е. программа не могла найти эту библиотеку (DLL файл). Если что, он лежит по пути: **\Python\Lib\site-packages\pymunk\chipmunk.dll**. Простите новичка =) Всем, кто ответил в комментариях - всё равно большое спасибо, что откликнулись =)

Comment: Вам нужно было писать, что уже используете `<xxx>` для сборки и возникла `<xxx>` проблема :) Обновите, пожалуйста, вопрос указав библиотеку для сборки и используемый скрипт для сборки, а в ответе напишите как тот скрипт сборки поменялся